# Heap sort implementation in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel, heap-sort

**This code relies on Python3.7.4**

I'm learning Heapsort in python 3. Please show me the errors in my code. Runs on my computer but tell me if Python rules or not.

```
class Heap:
    '''constructor'''
    def __init__(self,lis):
        self.lis=lis
        self.a=[]
    def heapify(self,i):
        self.r=(i-1)//2 #To get the root node
        '''To swap value'''
        if self.lis[i]<self.lis[self.r]:
            self.lis[i],self.lis[self.r]=self.lis[self.r],self.lis[i] 
    def heapSort(self):
        # Build a minheap.
        for j in range(len(self.lis)):
            for i in range(len(self.lis)-1,-1,-1):
                if i==0:
                    self.a.append(self.lis[0])
                    self.lis.remove(self.lis[0])
                else:        
                    self.heapify(i)
        else:
            return self.a

    obj=Heap([5,4,3,2,1])
    print(obj.heapSort())
```

Comment: Does it produce the requested output?

Comment: _tell me if Python rules or not._ Yes, Python rules.

Comment: Yes, it gives output.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Style

I suggest you check PEP0008 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ the official Python style guide when you write your code and Flake8 for style enforcement. The following goes accordingly:

- **Blank lines:** Surround top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines. Method definitions inside a class are surrounded by a single blank line. Extra blank lines may be used (sparingly) to separate groups of related functions. Blank lines may be omitted between a bunch of related one-liners (e.g. a set of dummy implementations). No blank lines are left between your function definitions.
- **Docstrings:** Python Docstring is the documentation string which is string literal, and it occurs in the class, module, function or method definition, and it is written as a first statement. Docstrings are accessible from the doc attribute for any of the Python object and also with the built-in help() function can come in handy. Whenever someone using your code is running `help(Heap)` this will print 'Constructor' which is invalid to what the help function is made for, you should include a description to the class. I suggest you run `help(list)` might give you some insights on how docstrings might look like. And none of your methods contain docstrings while they should.

  ```
  def heapSort(self):
      # Build a minheap.
  ```

  instead of writing a comment, use a docstring:

  ```
  def heap_sort(self):
      """Build a min heap."""
  ```
- **Space around binary operators:** a space should be left on both sides of an operator (+-/*&^**//==!=) `self.lis=lis` should be `self.lis = lis` `self.a=[]` should be `self.a = []` `if i==0:` should be `if i == 0:` ...
- **Descriptive variable names:**  `self.lis=lis` what is `lis`? if you're referring to `list` the common convention is when an identifier conflicts with a built-in function/type it should be written with a trailing underscore: `list_`
  `self.a=[]` what is `a` a name should reflect the object it represents. `self.r=(i-1)//2` what is `r`? what is `i`? ...
- **Variable names:** method names should be `lower_case_with_underscores` as well as variable names. `def heapSort(self):` should be `def heap_sort(self):`
- **Comments:**  `'''To swap value'''` in `heapify()` second line should be replaced with an inline comment `# To swap value`

## Code

- `def __init__(self,lis):` a class with a single parameter is not a good class, only functions that pass stuff are sufficient.
- `self.r=(i-1)//2` instance attribute defined outside the constructor in `heapify()` method.
- **main guard:** Use `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard at the end of your script which allows your module to be imported without running the whole script.

  ```
  obj=Heap(xyz)
  print(obj.heapSort())
  ```

  **should be written:**

  ```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
      obj = Heap(xyz)
      print(obj.heapSort())
  ```

Comment: Thank a lot bullseye to spending your valuable time to get the review of my code.

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to use an upvote (^ sign) if you found that helpful and whenever you decide a best answer, you might accept (check sign) the review to indicate that you no longer need answers.

Answer (score 6):

Most of what I say here is covered in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

- In assignment statements, surround an "=" with a space on either side.
- Function parameters are separated by a comma followed by another space
- If `'''To swap value'''` is a docstring, it needs up one line.
- Comparison operators like "<" also need a space on either side.
- Use variables with meaningful names. a, lis, j, and i are not meaningful.
- Comma seperation in tuple assignment should also have a space after each comma.
- `if i==0:` can be replaced with `if not i:`

I myself lack experience with sorts and time-complexity, so I'll leave that to others.

Comment: Thank a lot Gloweye to spending your valuable time to get the review of my code. Let me correct as per your suggestion and get back to you. Today I learned many coding fundamentals and styles from your suggestions. Thanks a lot once again

Comment: if `i == 0:` can be replaced with `if not i:` and not `if i:`

Answer (score 0):

**Code after the suggestion**

```
class Heap:
    def __init__(self,List):
        self.List = List
        self.a = []
    def heapify(self,i):
        #To swap variable
        # (i-1) // 2 = is get the root node
        if self.List[i] < self.List[(i-1) // 2]:
                self.List[i] , self.List[(i-1) // 2] = self.List[(i-1) // 2] , self.List[i] 
    def heapSort(self):
        # Build a minheap.
        for i in range(len(self.List)-1,-1,-1):
            if not i:
                self.a.append(self.List[0])
                self.List.remove(self.List[0])
            else:        
                self.heapify(i)
        else:
            if self.List:
                self.heapSort()
        return self.a

if __name__=="__main__":
    obj=Heap([5,4,3,2,1])
    print(obj.heapSort())
```

Comment: Could you explain what has changed to initial code? A code dump doesn't do so well around here.